# Working with Ogg files using Python

Tags: python, windows, audio, ogg

I have an "oggscissors.py" script which can cut and join ogg files. It needs pyogg and pyvorbis bindings. When I'm trying to execute this script Python interpreter crashes. The source code of this script is:

```
import getopt
import ogg.vorbis
import sys

def usage():
    print 'usage:'
    print '  oggscissors.py --analyze file.ogg'
    print "  oggscissors.py --from=startpos --upto=endpos in.ogg out.ogg"
    sys.exit("  oggscissors.py --join in1.ogg in2.ogg out.ogg")

def analyze_packets(fin, filenamein):

    count = None
    copied = 0
    written = 0
    pageno = 0

    instream = None

    insync = ogg.OggSyncState()

    while count == None or copied < count:
        b = fin.read(65536)
        if not b:
            break
        insync.bytesin(b)

        skipped = 1
        while skipped != 0:
            skipped, page = insync.pageseek()
            print 'read', skipped, 'bytes:', page
            if skipped > 0:
                if instream and page.serialno() != serialno:
                    print 'we hit a chain boundary, leaving'
                    break
                if not instream:
                    serialno = page.serialno()
                    instream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                page.pageno = pageno
                pageno = pageno + 1
                instream.pagein(page)
                while 1:
                    p = instream.packetout()
                    if not p:
                        break
                    print '  read', p
                    copied = copied + 1
            elif skipped < 0:
                print 'skipped', -skipped, 'bytes'


def count_packets(fin):
    print 'Counting packets',

    fin.seek(0)
    count = 0
    instream = None
    insync = ogg.OggSyncState()

    while 1:
        b = fin.read(65536)
        if not b:
            break
        insync.bytesin(b)

        skipped = 1
        while skipped != 0:
            skipped, page = insync.pageseek()
            if skipped > 0:
                if instream and page.serialno() != serialno:
                    print 'we hit a chain boundary, leaving'
                    break
                if not instream:
                    serialno = page.serialno()
                    instream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                instream.pagein(page)
                while 1:
                    p = instream.packetout()
                    if not p:
                        break
                    #print '  read', p
                    count = count + 1
            elif skipped < 0:
                print 'skipped', -skipped, 'bytes'

    fin.seek(0)
    print count
    return count


def copy_packets(fin, fout, outstream=None, skip_packets=0, count=0, written_pages=0, written_packets=0, granule_delta=0, last_chunk=0):

    fin.seek(0)

    copied = 0
    written = 0
    orig_packetno = 0
    granule_skip = 0

    if last_chunk and count == 0:
        total_packets = count_packets(fin) - skip_packets

    instream = None

    insync = ogg.OggSyncState()

    if skip_packets: print 'Skipping packets', skip_packets,

    while count == 0 or copied < count:
        b = fin.read(65536)
        if not b:
            break
        insync.bytesin(b)

        skipped = 1
        while skipped != 0:
            skipped, page = insync.pageseek()
            if skipped > 0:
                if instream and page.serialno() != serialno:
                    print 'we hit a chain boundary'
                    # we hit a chain boundary
                    break
                if not instream:
                    serialno = page.serialno()
                    instream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                    if not outstream:
                        outstream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                #print 'reading', page
                instream.pagein(page)
                while count == 0 or copied < count:
                    p = instream.packetout()
                    if not p:
                        break
                    if (skip_packets > 0):
                        #print '  skipping', p, 'yet to skip:', skip_packets
                        skip_packets = skip_packets - 1
                        orig_packetno = orig_packetno + 1
                        if p.granulepos != -1:
                            granule_skip = p.granulepos
                        if skip_packets % 1000 == 0: print skip_packets,
                        if skip_packets == 1: print
                        continue
                    #print '  reading', p
                    if p.eos:
                        p.eos = 0
                    if last_chunk:
                        if count > 0:
                            if copied + 1 == count:
                                p.eos = 512
                        else:
                            if copied + 1 == total_packets:
                                p.eos = 512
                    if written_packets >= 3:
                        if samples.has_key(orig_packetno):
                            granule_delta = granule_delta + samples[orig_packetno]
                        else:
                            granule_delta = granule_delta + 1024
                            print 'Unknown size of packet', orig_packetno
                        p.granulepos = granule_delta
                    #print '  writing', p
                    outstream.packetin(p)
                    copied = copied + 1
                    written_packets = written_packets + 1
                    orig_packetno = orig_packetno + 1
                    if copied % 1000 == 0: print copied,
                    if copied % 25000 == 0:
                        print
                        written_pages, written, outstream = dump_pages(outstream, written_pages, written)
            elif skipped < 0:
                print 'skipped', -skipped, 'bytes'

    print copied
    written_pages, written, outstream = dump_pages(outstream, written_pages, written)

    return (written, written_pages, written_packets, outstream, granule_delta)


def dump_pages(outstream, written_pages, written):

    print 'Dumping pages',

    while 1:
        pg = outstream.flush()
        if not pg:
            break
        pg.pageno = written_pages
        #print 'writing', pg
        written = written + pg.writeout(fout)
        #print 'written', written, 'bytes so far'
        written_pages = written_pages + 1
        if written_pages % 100 == 0: print written_pages,

    print written_pages
    return written_pages, written, outstream


def get_packetno(seconds, rate):
    needed_samples = seconds * rate
    for z in samples:
        needed_samples = needed_samples - samples[z]
        if needed_samples <= 0:
            break
    return z


def get_samples(filenamein):
    print 'Scanning packets'
    vf = ogg.vorbis.VorbisFile(filenamein)
    pcm_prev = 0
    packetno = 3
    samples = {}
    while 1:
        (buff, bytes, bit) = vf.read(4096)
        if bytes == 0:
            break
        pcm_now = vf.pcm_tell()
        samples[packetno] = pcm_now - pcm_prev
        if samples[packetno] > 1024:
            print "Clipping bogus packet", packetno, "sample size", samples[packetno], "to 1024"
            samples[packetno] = 1024
        pcm_prev = pcm_now
        packetno = packetno + 1
        if packetno % 1000 == 0: print packetno,
    (buff, bytes,bit) = vf.read(4096)
    vinfo = vf.info()
    return samples, vinfo.rate

def renumber_pages(filenamein):
    filenameout = filenamein+".fixed.ogg"
    print
    print "Hole detected! Fixing ogg file and writing it to", filenameout
    fin = open(filenamein, 'rb')
    fout = open(filenameout, 'wb')
    insync = ogg.OggSyncState()
    instream = None
    outstream = None
    pageno = 0

    while 1:
        b = fin.read(65536)
        if not b:
            break
        insync.bytesin(b)
        skipped = 1
        while skipped != 0:
            skipped, page = insync.pageseek()
            if skipped > 0:
                if instream and page.serialno() != serialno:
                    print "we hit a chain boundary, leaving"
                    break
                if not instream:
                    serialno = page.serialno()
                    instream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                if not outstream:
                    outstream = ogg.OggStreamState(serialno)
                instream.pagein(page)
                #print "in -- ", page
                while 1:
                    try:
                        p = instream.packetout()
                    except ogg.OggError:
                        instream.reset()
                        instream.pagein(page)
                        p = instream.packetout()
                    if not p:
                        break
                    outstream.packetin(p)
                while 1:
                    pg = outstream.flush()
                    if not pg:
                        break
                    pg.writeout(fout)
                    #print "out - ", pg

    fin.close()
    fout.close()
    return filenameout

opts, pargs = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['analyze', 'join', 'from=', 'upto='])
opt_analyze = opt_join = 0
startpos = -1
endpos = -1

for option, argument in opts:
    if option == '--from':
        try:
            startpos = float(argument)
        except ValueError:
            usage()
    elif option == '--upto':
        try:
            endpos = float(argument)
        except ValueError:
            usage()
    elif option == '--analyze':
        opt_analyze = 1
    elif option == '--join':
        opt_join = 1
    else:
        usage()

if opt_analyze:
    if len(pargs) != 1:
        usage()

    filenamein = pargs[0]
    fin = open(filenamein, 'rb')
    analyze_packets(fin, filenamein)

elif opt_join:
    if len(pargs) != 3:
        usage()

    filenamein = pargs[0]
    try:
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    except ogg.vorbis.VorbisError, errorString:
        filenamein = renumber_pages(filenamein)
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    fin = open(filenamein, 'rb')

    filenameout = pargs[2]
    fout = open(filenameout, 'wb')

    n, pages, packets, os, grskip = copy_packets(fin, fout, None, 0, 3)
    n, pages, packets, os, grskip = copy_packets(fin, fout, os, 3, 0, pages, packets, grskip)

    filenamein = pargs[1]
    try:
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    except ogg.vorbis.VorbisError, errorString:
        filenamein = renumber_pages(filenamein)
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    fin = open(filenamein, 'rb')

    n, pages, packets, os, grskip = copy_packets(fin, fout, os, 3, 0, pages, packets, grskip, 1)

else:
    if len(pargs) != 2:
        usage()

    filenamein = pargs[0]
    try:
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    except ogg.vorbis.VorbisError, errorString:
        filenamein = renumber_pages(filenamein)
        samples, rate = get_samples(filenamein)
    fin = open(filenamein, 'rb')

    filenameout = pargs[1]
    fout = open(filenameout, 'wb')

    n, pages, packets, os, grskip = copy_packets(fin, fout, None, 0, 3)

    if startpos > -1:
        startpacket = get_packetno(startpos, rate)
    else:
        startpacket = 3

    if startpacket > 5:
        startpacket = startpacket - 2

    if endpos > -1:
        endpacket = get_packetno(endpos, rate)
        count = endpacket - startpacket
    else:
        count = 0

    n, pages, packets, os, grskip = copy_packets(fin, fout, os, startpacket, count, pages, packets, grskip, 1)
```

It crashes in the "vf = ogg.vorbis.VorbisFile(filenamein)" string of get_samples method. Can anyone help me solving this problem? Maybe I compiled the vorbis module incorrectly?